# Allow user to select account without logging out

Tags: google-plus

I'm trying to use Google+ Signin for a client and they require that only people in their own domain be allowed to sign in. The issue is that when I hit my test page, I'm automatically signed in with my current gmail account. My code correctly handles this (it notices I'm not using a @theclient.com address), but I can't seem to find a way to let the user pick an account.

I could call logout - but I don't want to log the user out of other tabs he may be using. I simply want the popup to show and let me select another account.

I do see a quick flash of a popup but it auto dismisses itself.

Any options outside of a forced logout?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simultaneously be signed into the same site with two accounts, this could create a whole mess of issues. Users can use [multiple account profiles](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en), incognito windows, and other browser features to access resources with multiple accounts.

Note: `gapi.auth.signout` will sign the user out only for your site, allowing users to switch accounts if they have multiple accounts currently available.

Comment: The issue is, the users for this app won't be technically savvy. They have (or may have) a @gmail.com as well as the corporate account. So the only way I can let them sign on with the corp account if they had been using gmail in another tab is to completely sign them out?

Comment: Comment added to answer.

Comment: Hmm. I could have sworn that signout logged us out of everything. I'll give it a shot.